# Leaking memory, freeing objects and object "copying"

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

This is not a question about deep copying or cloning objects, as there's millions of those already, despite the fact that that's what i've been looking for myself at first and would probably fall back on it if it was my only option. But it seems unnecessarily overcomplicated for a simple thing like this.

I've been translating some C++ code to Delphi, basically blatantly copying a Tetris using SDL according to [this](http://aaroncox.net/tutorials/arcade/FallingBlocks6.html). It's been a learning experience, in regard of SDL, but now also in a Delphi kind of way. I'm linking to the particular page that has code that I cannot fully translate. The game works as intended, but there comes a point where I have to switch the block that is currently falling and add its squares to the others that are at the bottom, and then set the next block as the currently falling one.

Here's some of my code without copying too much: `TSingleSquare`, `TBlock` and the `ChangeFocusBlock` procedure.

```
TSingleSquare = class
  private
    S_TextureSurf: pSDL_SURFACE;
    S_BlockType: TBlockType;
    S_CenterX, S_CenterY: integer;
  public
    constructor Create(CX, CY: integer; T: pSDL_SURFACE; BT: TBlockType);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Draw(W: pSDL_SURFACE);
    procedure Move(D: TDirection);
    function GetCenterX: integer;
    function GetCenterY: integer;
    procedure SetCenterX(lX: integer);
    procedure SetCenterY(lY: integer);
  end;

Ttmp_ar = array of integer;
TSquaresArray = array of TSingleSquare;

TBlock = class
  private
    B_CenterX, B_CenterY: integer;
    B_BlockType: TBlockType;
    B_SquaresArray: TSquaresArray;
    B_TextureSurf: pSDL_SURFACE;
  public
    constructor Create(CX, CY: integer; TS: pSDL_SURFACE; BT: TBlockType);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure SetupSquares(SX, SY: integer);
    procedure Draw(W: pSDL_SURFACE);
    procedure Move(D: TDirection);
    procedure Rotate;
    function GetRotatedSquares: Ttmp_ar;
    function GetSquaresArray: TSquaresArray;
    function GetBlockType: TBlockType;
  end;

procedure ChangeFocusBlock;
var
  Square_ar: TSquaresArray;
  i: integer;
begin
  Square_ar := g_FocusBlock.GetSquaresArray
  SetLength(g_OldSquares, (Length(g_OldSquares) + Length(Square_ar)));
  for i := Low(Square_ar) to High(Square_ar) do
    begin
      g_OldSquares[i+Length(g_OldSquares)-Length(Square_ar)] := Square_ar[i];
      Square_ar[i] := nil;
    end;
  g_FocusBlock := nil;
  g_FocusBlock := g_NextBlock;
  g_NextBlock := nil;
  g_FocusBlock.SetupSquares(BLOCK_START_X, BLOCK_START_Y);
  g_NextBlock := TBlock.Create(NEXT_BLOCK_CIRCLE_X, NEXT_BLOCK_CIRCLE_Y, GameBitmap, TBlockType(Random(11)));
end;
```

I know that I'm not freeing `g_FocusBlock` and this is where I'm leaking memory, but I can't find an appropriate place to free it in the first place and if I leave it like this, leaking memory is my only issue. Once I started looking for a solution, it bit me in the ass later when i try to iterate over `g_OldSquares` and I understand why, the squares are still pointing to the `g_FocusBlock` squares which were supposed to be freed. My confusion comes in when I add breakpoints at every step and observe what is happening to the values, everything seems in order with `g_OldSquares` after `g_FocusBlock` is freed, after i set it to `g_NextBlock` and create a new next block. However later iterating over `g_OldSquares` I notice that part of the squares are getting overwritten, as in memory is getting reused? I suddenly cant trust the Watchlist values to be true?

Bottom line of this wall of text is that I would like to understand what is happening with `g_OldSquares` and why it's values do not change even thought the addresses are the same when inspecting via watchlist.

But more importantly what would be proper course of action to make this work properly? I am aware of using `TPersistent` and overriding it's `Assign` to be able to actually assign objects between each other (although I'm not fully sure how to accomplish that either), but right here I still have to get rid of the "link" or shared memory (I apologize for any incorrectly used words, i'm not really fluent in *programming*) between `g_OldSquares` and `g_FocusBlock` to be able to free the latter.

Let the shaming begin.

Edit:

AccessViolation occurs when i do this

```
for i := Low(g_OldSquares) to High(g_OldSquares) do
  begin
    row := (g_OldSquares[i].GetCenterY - top) div row_size;
    Inc(squares_in_row[row])
  end;

constructor TBlock.Create(CX, CY: integer; TS: pSDL_Surface; BT: TBlockType);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  B_CenterX := CX;
  B_CenterY := CY;
  B_BlockType := BT;
  B_TextureSurf:= TS;

  case BT of
    SQUARE_BLOCK..REVERSE_S_BLOCK: SetLength(B_SquaresArray, 4);
    STRAIGHT_TRI_BLOCK..BENT_TRI_BLOCK: SetLength(B_SquaresArray, 3);
    TWO_BLOCK: SetLength(B_SquaresArray, 2);
    DOT_BLOCK: SetLength(B_SquaresArray, 1);
  end;

  SetupSquares(CX, CY);
end;

destructor TBlock.Destroy;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := Low(B_SquaresArray) to High(B_SquaresArray) do
    B_SquaresArray[i].Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: u may look into `TInterrfacedObject ` for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting

Comment: You create an object and take a reference to it. Then, later, you abandon your reference to that abject and make the reference refer to a different object. It is at that point, just before you abandon the object, that you need to free it. And yes, automatic reference counting with interfaces would do the job.

Comment: if there is no any other link to the object (and if you say about memory leak, then probably there are not) then `g_FocusBlock := nil;` is probably removing the last link and thus should be replaced with `g_FocusBlock.Free`. However if you would use reference-counted memory model then `g_FocusBlock := nil;` would (asusmed that was a last pointer) really free the object for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting your sources from http://aaroncox.net/tutorials/arcade/FallingBlocks6.html

```
delete g_FocusBlock; // delete the current focus block
g_FocusBlock = g_NextBlock; // set the focus block to the next block
g_FocusBlock->SetupSquares(...);

// Set the next block to a new block of random type 
g_NextBlock = new cBlock(...);
```

well, then just translate it exactly as it goes.

```
g_FocusBlock.Free; // delete the current focus block
g_FocusBlock := g_NextBlock; // set the focus block to the next block
g_FocusBlock.SetupSquares( ... );

// Set the next block to a new block of random type 
g_NextBlock := TBlock.Create(...);
```

Is there anythign like `g_FocusBlock = NULL;` in your C++ sources? No. Then your invented `g_FocusBlock := nil;` in Delphi source jst does not relate to the actual program and is but your fantasy.

It coul make sense if you would create code based on [refcounting memopry model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) and `TInterfacedObject` but you're translating plain-old-objects code with manual memory management, then just do exactly what C++ code does.

---

Suggestion: make `g_OldSquares` of a `TList<TSingleSquare>` type or maybe `TQueue<TSingleSquare>`.

Then you would just do

```
g_OldSquares.AddRange(Square_ar);
```

or at least

```
for Square in Square_ar do g_OldSquares.Add(Square);
```

to move items from that array. More safe than all that gymnastics with index variables and array boundaries, where you can easily stumble upon some typical "off by one" error.

PS: `TObjectList<T>` with option `OwnsObjects := True` might be even easier to code against.

---

Now, now...

```
destructor TBlock.Destroy;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := Low(B_SquaresArray) to High(B_SquaresArray) do
    B_SquaresArray[i].Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

show me this code here: http://aaroncox.net/tutorials/arcade/FallingBlocks2.html can you?

Let us look what are you doing now!

1. You created those squares and put the pointers to them into `TBlock.BSquares_Array`
2. inside `procedure ChangeFocusBlock` you move those pointers to those `Square` objects into the new container - the `g_OldSquares`
3. Then you try to destroy those squares int the `TBlock.Destroy` despite those objects still have pointers from `g_OldSquares`.

That is redundant at best and dangerous at worst. Now i have to demand you show `g_FocusBlock.GetSquaresArray` implementation - what does happen there ?
And i demand you to debug the `TBlock.Destroy` and check if the array by any mistake still contains any non-nil value.

---

> AccessViolation occurs when i do this

```
(*1*)  for i := Low(g_OldSquares) to High(g_OldSquares) do
          begin
(*2*)          row := (g_OldSquares[i].GetCenterY - top) div row_size;
(*3*)          Inc(squares_in_row[row])
          end;
```

Here are three lines of code. Which line does result with an AV ?
What are specifics of this of AV, is it reading or writing and at which location ?

---

moving out of chat for record

```
delete g_OldSquares[index]; 
g_OldSquares.erase(g_OldSquares.begin() + index); 
index--;
```

i guess you'd better rewrite it to while-loop (and modifying the variable) instead of introducing the bug-prone delayed nil squashing.

actually there is a neat trick - the thing is about loop direction, when you can delete the element - but safely avoiding enumeratinf some element twice or skip some another element

```
for i := TList.Count-1 downto 0 do 
  if SomeCondition then TList.Delete[i];
```

Using this you can take

```
for j := Low(g_OldSquares) to High(g_OldSquares) do 
 if (g_OldSquares[j] <> nil) then 
   if ((g_OldSquares[j].GetCenterY - top) div row_size) = i then 
   begin 
     g_OldSquares[j].Free; 
     g_OldSquares[j] := nil; 
   end;
```

and refactor it into

```
for j := High(g_OldSquares) downto Low(g_OldSquares) do 
    if g_OldSquares[j].Row = i then 
       g_OldSquares.Delete(j);
```

assuming `g_OldSquares` was converted to `TObjectList<TSquare>` type with `OwnsObjects` property set to `True`.

Comment: If I do this, I end up with an AccessViolation error as soon as the block hits the ground, actually it's a little bit later, when i iterate over g_OldSquares. And yes, I agree, nilling it doesnt make much sense but it was for my own sanity that i needed it, since i couldnt free it...

Comment: then you should debug that AV instead. what ois the exact statement where it appears and what is the exact error text details ? PS. you told "leaking memory is my only issue" but now ti appears what you told was untrue :-( That would alas affect the trust to the rest of details you say...

Comment: show your code for TBlock constructor and destructor. I can see that the original code just does not have any destructor there! http://aaroncox.net/tutorials/arcade/FallingBlocks2.html

Comment: question edited, leaky memory was the only issue, if i free the object then i get access violations, maybe my logic was backwards and the real issue was not leaky memory but the error. I am in the process of changing g_OldSquares to a TList and later TQueue to see if that helps.

Comment: use backticks to highlight the source code text, where `TList<T>` and `TList` would be rendered differently, not sikpping `<T>` part. `TQueue<T>` is just somewhat optimized towards "inserting fro mone end, deleting from another" that maybe would be somewhat better for Tetris...

Comment: Your goal was to make an exact copy of C++ code. The AV made you jumpo off the road and started deviating from the template code you chosen. And you think that is not an error? ;-)

Comment: My goal was to make it to work in delphi not to copy paste it and I almost did it :D It was working FINE untill i added `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;` before that I was confident everything was working perfect, from there I tried to free stuff and get AV. TBlock destructor/constructor added to the main question btw

Comment: you may also look into `TObjectList<TSquare>.Create(OwnsObject == True)`. PS. i updated the answer.

Comment: `GetSquaresArray` just returns the `B_SquaresArray` as the `Result`. Removing the TSingleSquare.Free from the destructor changed the memory leak type from TBlock to TSingleSquare, but also no AV now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33480/discussion-between-raith-and-arioch-the)

Comment: Despite Delphi does not COW (copy-on-write) for dynarrays like it does for strings,  so `Square_ar[i] := nil;` should have been executed... that still looks redundant and dangerous...

Comment: Now, as far as i remember Tetris, the squares disappear when you scroll the screen downwards and remove bottom completed lines, is this so ? can you show both source C++ code and your Delphi code that removes full lines from `g_OldSquares` ? By the game logic THAT code should destroy squares when they are REMOVED FROM SCREEN - thus no more needed for game playing.